# get string to html5 date filed failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an error in my console saying `The specified value '2015/20/05' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.`

But my string already formatted to yyyy-MM-dd.

```
var d = '2015/20/05';

$('input[name="dob"]').val(d);
```

What is the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/Luk72czg/

Answer (score 1):

Try this out http://jsfiddle.net/Luk72czg/2/

```
var d = '2015-05-20';

$('input[name="dob"]').val(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use dash instead of slash.

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit and maybe add a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Your string is the wrong format... you're using `yyyy/dd/MM` instead of `yyyy-MM-dd`. Your string should be `2015-05-20`.

Answer (score 0):

use below code   . [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Luk72czg/3/)

read more about date control [HERE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

> HTML5 Date control accepts in the format of Year-month-day same as
>   used in SQL

you need to use `-` like `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of `/`

```
var d = '2015-05-20';
$('input[name="dob"]').val(d);
```